# Preventing double jumping

Tags: javascript, canvas

```js
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement}*/
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
const canvasHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight

//document.addEventListener('keyup', keyRelease)

const playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = 'images/spriteRunRight.png'
const platformImage = new Image();
platformImage.src = 'images/platform.png'

class Player {
    constructor(){
        this.x = 100
        this.y = 540
        this.velocityX = 0
        this.velocityY = 0
        this.speed = 10
        this.gravity = 0.5
        this.width = 130
        this.height = 160
        this.spriteW = 341
        this.spriteH = 400
        this.frameX = 0
        this.frameY = 0
        this.image = playerImage
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.drawImage(playerImage, this.frameX * this.spriteW, this.frameY * this.spriteH , this.spriteW, this.spriteH, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
    }
    update(){
    this.draw()
        this.y += this.velocityY
        this.x += this.velocityX

        if(this.y + this.height + this.velocityY <= canvas.height){
            this.velocityY += this.gravity
        } else this.velocityY = 0
    }

}
const player = new Player()
addEventListener('keydown', ({keyCode}) => {
    switch(keyCode){
        case 87: //up
            player.velocityY -= 20
        break;
    }
})
```

How can I prevent double jumping, I want if my player jumped, then he can't jump again till he lands. I tried to put if statements in my switch case but it didn't work, currently my player just flies off if I hold w.

Comment: Could you make that snippet into a working one, looks like you just need to add the HTML bit..

Comment: You could set a flag, `isJumping`. Set it to true when the jump-key is pressed and the velocity of Y is 0. And set it back to false when velocity of Y returns to 0. With this flag in place, anytime the jump button is pressed, check to see if the playing `isJumping` before you modify the velocity any further.

Answer (score 0):

you can test if the player velocity is equal to 0 before add the velocity

```js
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement}*/
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const canvasWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth
const canvasHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight


//document.addEventListener('keyup', keyRelease)

const playerImage = new Image();
playerImage.src = 'images/spriteRunRight.png'
const platformImage = new Image();
platformImage.src = 'images/platform.png'

class Player {
    constructor(){
        this.x = 100
        this.y = 540
        this.velocityX = 0
        this.velocityY = 0
        this.speed = 10
        this.gravity = 0.5
        this.width = 130
        this.height = 160
        this.spriteW = 341
        this.spriteH = 400
        this.frameX = 0
        this.frameY = 0
        this.image = playerImage
    }
    draw(){
        ctx.drawImage(playerImage, this.frameX * this.spriteW, this.frameY * this.spriteH , this.spriteW, this.spriteH, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
    }
    update(){
    this.draw()
        this.y += this.velocityY
        this.x += this.velocityX

        if(this.y + this.height + this.velocityY <= canvas.height){
            this.velocityY += this.gravity
        } else {
           this.velocityY = 0
        } 
    }

}
const player = new Player()
addEventListener('keydown', ({keyCode}) => {
    switch(keyCode){
        case 87: //up
            if(player.velocityY==0){
        
               player.velocityY -= 20
             }
      
        break;
    }
})
```

Comment: if you check if it's <= 0, then when they start falling down they can double jump again no?

Comment: yes i modify this and velocity should be equal to 0